# Efficient way to lock std::list

Tags: c++, multithreading, list

I am aware that `std::list` is not thread safe. In my application threads keep adding elements to a global list. Another thread get elements from list and processes them one by one. However, **I don't want processing thread to lock the list all the time while processing is being done.**

So processing thread locks list, gets element, unlocks list and processes the element. While processing in progress, other threads keep adding elements to the list. Once processing is over, processing thread again locks list deletes processed element and unlocks it.

Below is pseudo-code:

```
std::list<int> mylist ; /* Global list of integers */

void add_thread(int element) /* Threads adding element to the list */
{
   write_lock();
   mylist.push_back(element);
   write_unlock();

   return;
}

void list_processing_thread() /* Processes elements from the list */
{
    for (std::list<int>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
    {
        read_lock();
        int element = *it;
        read_unlock();

        process_element(element);

        write_lock();
        mylist.remove(element);
        write_unlock();
    }

    return;
}
```

Is it correct approach (to process list elements in efficient manner) ? Will it cause any trouble ?

Comment: Your scenario is multiple producers, one consumer, is that right?

Comment: @Maxim yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> So processing thread locks list, gets element, unlocks list and processes the element. While processing in progress, other threads keep adding elements to the list. Once processing is over, processing thread again locks list deletes processed element and unlocks it.

Producer threads contend with each other and with the consumer thread for access to the list.

You can eliminate the contention between producers by giving each producer its own queue (std::list + std::mutex or a spinlock). This way:

1. Producers post items into its own queues. Create a temporary `std::list` of one element, then lock the mutex, splice that element into the queue, unlock the mutex.
2. When the consumer is ready, it locks those producer queues one by one and splices the elements into its own queue. Splicing `std::list` is O(1) operation.
3. If ordering is required each element should have a timestamp, so that the consumer can sort all elements in its consolidated queue by time.

The above method also makes your critical sections very short because all you do while the mutex is locked is `std::list` splicing, which is just a few pointer modifications.

Alternatively, just use [concurrent_bounded_queue](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506201) class from Intel® Threading Building Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not safe. Yes it will cause trouble.
To Elaborate:
There should only be one lock which is the write lock. Readers don't need to defend from each other.
You need to get the lock in the processing thread before you access begin and end iterators as they may be corrupted by the writing thread. After you get the lock, copy the list, and release the lock. When finished processing, get the lock, and edit the original list.
Good luck

Comment: read lock because while threads reading concurrently writer can wait...?

Comment: Yes Andrew, the readers need to not read while the writer is writing, so the correct lock here might be a read/write lock, which allows multiple readers but blocks them out while the writer has the (exclusive) write lock.

Comment: In this case it seems there are multiple writers and one reader ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution to your problem, in C++11, but you can easily port it to C++-03 + boost or whatever thread library you have:

```
std::deque<int> queue;
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable ready;

void producer()
{
  while (true)
  {
    int element = produce();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    queue.push_back(element);
    lock.unlock(); 
    ready.notify_one();
  }
}

void consumer()
{
  while (true)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    ready.wait(lock, [](){ ! queue.empty() });
    int element = queue.front();
    queue.pop_front();
    lock.unlock();

    consume(element);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit naive implementation. `queue.push_back(element);` allocates memory while the mutex is locked - poor scalability. This is why `std::list` is better in this case as you can allocate a new element and then lock the mutex and splice it into the destination list, making your critical section really fast - 4 pointer updates only.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things you could do with different levels of performance, but two very simple ones:

- use [std::list::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/swap/) in the processing thread to swap the queue with an empty one, that way if lock contention is slowing things down at least you'll be getting all of the backlog of items in one hit, minimising the harm
- use a single-writer / many-reader lock (e.g. [posix_rwlock_rdlock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.html) et al)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the approach is good, you SHOULD lock for a short period, get the current item, unlock, and process the item while the list is unlocked and accessible for other threads to use.

But, I would recommend that you didn't rely on an list iterator while the list is not locked. Iterators are sneaky, and many data structures may corrupt the iterator when items are added/removed from them.

I would suggest you use the following approach:

```
while(list.empty() == false)
{
  lock();
  int element = list.front();
  list.pop_front();
  unlock();

  process(element);
}
```

best!

Comment: Thanks. But `list.empty()` will work even while elements are being added to the `list`? OR need to lock there also ?

Comment: Yes, you need the lock to call `list.empty()`.
Furthermore, you need some conditional variable to wait, if the list is empty (producers slower than consumer will lead to spinning in consumer).

Comment: Keeping check on `list.empty()` becomes little tricky when we want to delete element only when processing is successful :) And we cannot use iterators also as you mentioned in your answer.